# Adjusting php code to accommodate a 2nd div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

long time reader first time poster. I downloaded a theme for wordpress recently and i'm trying to edit it but am having difficulty. I know a bit of css but php is slightly out of my capability. So anyway I have 3 excepts of pages which show up on the main page. I would like to give them different background colours. I've managed to give the first two the same colour and the last a different one. I would like to give the middle one a different color as well, but i don't know how to. It seems that the div control is managed through php. Here is the php code:

```
        <?php if ( get_option('chameleon_display_blurbs') == 'on' ){ ?>
        <div id="services" class="clearfix">
            <?php for ($i=1; $i <= 3; $i++) { ?>
                <?php query_posts('page_id=' . get_pageId(html_entity_decode(get_option('chameleon_home_page_'.$i)))); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <?php 
                        global $more; $more = 0;
                    ?>
                    <div class="service<?php if ( $i == 3 ) echo ' last'; ?>">
```

And here is the css code:

```
#services { margin-bottom: 40px; }
            .service { float: left; width: 244px; margin-right: 66px; background:#000; }        .last { margin-right: 0px; background:#0F0; }
```

So just to reiterate, I just want to be able to apply a different colour to the middle div.

website address:

Thank you and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to change this line:

```
<div class="service<?php if ( $i == 3 ) echo ' last'; ?>">
```

to

```
<div class="service<?php if ( $i == 3 ) echo ' last'; ?> service-<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

That will give each div a different class (`service-1`, `service-2`, and `service-3`) which you can style separately.

Comment: better learn about nth child selector. Also the last one can be easily styled with CSS and all these classes *shouldn't* be necessary any longer: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: Great point.  A much better solution if you don't need to support older browsers. @newtodesign - see [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) to see if you can use them on the browsers you're targetting